# Finding a holomorphic function with a prescribed real part.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am to find a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with $u(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $f(1)=1$. Preceding this, I had to show we could write $f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} -i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, which is clearly supposed to be a hint for this part.

The issue is I don't see how it helps at all. Other than taking $u(x,y)$ as I know it and doing lots of differentiation/integration along with the Cauchy Riemann equations (which would be a lot of work..) the only idea I had that used this as a hint was to compute $f'(z)$ with that formula, and see if it would arrange into an expression in $z$ which was readily integrable. I got to $f'(z(x,y)) = \dfrac{(y+ix)^2+i(y+ix)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, but given this all assumes $x$ is the real part, etc., you can't just swap $x$ and $y$ and there's no way to get to $x+iy$ nicely! so that approach seemed to fail..

This is a question from a past exam paper; one of the short 'more routine' questions in the first section. Typically these aren't so bad, but with this particular question is being more difficult to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $u(x,y) = \dfrac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x(x+y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{x^2+y^2-2x^2-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{-x^2-2xy+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

Likewise, by symmetry,

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{-y^2-2xy+x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$

Putting these together shows that

$$\begin{align} f'(z) &= \frac{-x^2-2xy+y^2-i(-y^2-2xy+x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\ &= \frac{-x^2-2xy+y^2+iy^2+2ixy-ix^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.\end{align}$$

The numerator can be rewritten a bit:

$$\begin{align}(-x^2+2ixy+y^2)+i(-x^2+2ixy+y^2) &= (1+i)(-x^2+2ixy+y^2) \\ &= -(1+i)(x^2-2ixy-y^2) \\ &= -(1+i)(x-iy)^2.\end{align}$$

Thus we have that

$$f'(z) = \frac{-(1+i)(x-iy)^2}{((x+iy)(x-iy))^2} = -\frac{1+i}{(x+iy)^2} = -\frac{1+i}{z^2}.$$

From here, it is a simple application of integration to get the final answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Of course, that's how I'd normally approach this; i.e., using $U$ and its derivatives to deduce suitable $V$, however the question asked for me to show we can write $f'(z) = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} -i\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, and *hence* find a holomorphic function. This first step isn't necessary usually, so I'd imagine it's supposed to help..

Comment: Oh I get it now. Your post was a bit confusing for me. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

A function $(x,y)\mapsto u(x,y)$ is (locally) the real part of a holomorphic function iff $u$ is harmonic, i.e. $\Delta u\equiv0$. One can check this before going on with the problem; but from the wording  it seems clear that the given $u$ is harmonic.

In a previous problem you have proven that when $u$ is the real part of the holomorphic function $f$ then
$$f'(x+iy)={\partial u\over\partial x}-i\>{\partial u\over\partial y}=:\Phi(x,y)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where the expression $\Phi(x,y)$ is obtained by actual computing of the partial derivatives of $u$. Your problem now seems to be the following:
How do we convert this formula into a formula containing $z$ instead of $x$ and $y\>$? The answer is simple: Substitute 
$$x:={z+\bar z\over2}\>,\qquad y:={z-\bar z\over 2i}\ .$$
Then $(1)$ becomes
$$f'(z)=\Phi\left({z+\bar z\over2},{z-\bar z\over 2i}\right)=:\Psi(z,\bar z)\ .$$
When $u$ was harmonic indeed then $f'$ will be a holomorphic function of the complex variable $z$, and this will *automatically* have the consequence that the variable $\bar z$ does not appear in the expression $\Psi$; therefore you are now in possession of a rational expression in $z$ that represents $f'(z)$.